« dépendre » ou « dépendre de » + interrogative
Lorsque le verbe « dépendre » est suivi d’une proposition interrogative, quand peut-il / doit-il utiliser la préposition « de » ?
Les verbes « savoir » et « (se) demander » peuvent être suivis directement d’une proposition interrogative. On peut donc s’attendre à ce que ce soit pareil avec « dépendre », qu’on dise :

Le déroulement de la soirée dépend qui viendra.
le résultat dépendra comment on s’y prend.

Pourtant, ça sonne étrange, et j’aurais tendance à préférer :

Le déroulement de la soirée dépend de qui viendra.
Le résultat dépendra de comment on s’y prend.

Après tout, on utilise « dépendre de + groupe nominal ».
Toutefois, je vois pleins d’exemples sans le « de » :

Cela dépend si l’on considère les personnes en bloc ou individuellement.
Ça dépend sur quoi on souhaite mettre l’accent.

Comment peut-on savoir quand mettre le « de » ?

Il serait intéressant de préciser dans ta question en quoi les réponses sur l'exacte même question posée sur question-orthographe ne te conviennent pas pour éviter que tu te retrouves avec les mêmes réponses que celles qui y ont été faites.

Les réponses sur le site question-orthographe traitent les exemples 3 à 6 comme incorrects ou maladroits, et proposent des reformulations avec un groupe nominal à la place. Or, j'ai quand même l'impression que "ça se dit". Je voulais savoir s'il existait une règle qui permette d'expliquer les exemples 3 à 6 tout en expliquant que les exemples 1 et 2 sonnent agrammaticaux.

Savoir et demander se construisent avec des COD, mais pas dépendre. On ne dit pas dépendre quelque chose, alors qu'on dit savoir quelque chose.

Ça dépend qui parle...

@jlliagre C'est un COD, ça?

Je ne pense pas mais la question n'est justement pas posée en ces termes. Ta réponse n'aborde pas clairement les points soulevés par DominiqueR qui concernent la présence ou non de la préposition de après le verbe dépendre.

@jlliagre Oui, mais je pensais que sans de, on se retrouvait en présence d'un COD qui ne passait pas bien avec dépendre, d'où ma semi-tangente sur les CODs.
